# google maps not updates once react app state changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Google maps component initially loads fine but how do I change the location?
I want to pass something else in lat/lng so I pass current state values.. but then map doesn't rerenader and change the location. But I can see new lat/lng props passed to Map.js

App.js

```
<Map id="myMap" options={{center: { lat: xxx, lng: yyy }, zoom: 13}}/>
```

Map.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Map extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onScriptLoad = this.onScriptLoad.bind(this)
  }

  onScriptLoad() {
    const map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(this.props.id), this.props.options)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (!window.google) {
      const script = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.src = `https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=${GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY}`;
      script.id = 'googleMaps';
      document.body.appendChild(script);
      script.addEventListener('load', e => {
        this.onScriptLoad()
      })
    }
    else {
      this.onScriptLoad()
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ width: 500, height: 500 }} id={this.props.id} />
    );
  }
}

export default Map;
```

Comment: You're not handling the new props on update. You need to update the map instance with the new lat/lng in a lifecycle method like `componentDidUpdate`. I'm not sure about the Google Map API and the object you're creating in `onScriptLoad`, but if you put it in a class attribute, i.e. `this.map = new window....`, then you can access it in `componentDidUpdate` and update it with the new lat/lng.

Comment: That works perfect.. Thank you Mr. Kaveh